# How to implement static cells in NSTableView?

Tags: nstableview

I have used static cells in a table to create a sort of settings panel in iOS. I would like to do the same in OS X.

XCode 7.3
Swift 2.2
OS X 10.11.4

Each cell in my NSTableView has different content (controls, text, etc.). I have designed the cells in IB but the table shows up blank when run. I have set the datasource to return the correct number of rows, but then only the first row is repeated. If it is anything like UITableView, then when creating static cells, I don't really need to deal with the typical datasource calls, but I can find no IB setting for Static cells on NSTableView.

I have found some reference to a property for an NSTableView called usesStaticContents, but setting that does not seem to do anything for me.

Can anyone point me to a reference or a tutorial that describes the process of creating static cells in NSTableView in XCode 7.3? I have Googled the heck out of this and not found anything useful.

Thank you.

Comment: By "static cells", I assume you mean cells whose contents do not change. Just implement the NSTableViewDataSource methods. I don't see what's the problem.